# Google Spreadsheet Conditionally Join

Tags: if-statement, join, google-sheets, filter, textjoin

I have spreadsheet with two columns.

```
|---|---------|
| 1 | 2382207 |
| 1 | 2382177 |
| 2 | 2382195 |
| 2 | 2382174 |
| 2 | 2382175 |
| 2 | 2382193 |
```

I want to join the contents of the second column together, with a `|` as the separator. I do with using `=JOIN("|",B1:B6)`

But now what I want is to only include those where the first column = 1. How could I do this conditionally join?

So the outcome that I want is `2382207|2382177`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use FILTER, `=JOIN("|",FILTER(B1:B6;A1:A6=1))`

Answer (score 0):

alternative:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; IF(A:A=1; B:B; )))
```